# How to understand the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand basic concept here. I know this is a common problem and pretty sure there's a simple explanation which I don't seem to get. Here I'm trying to access the different properties of my object which I'm unable to do so.

Below is my array output using `console.log(val);`

[image: browser output of this console]

When I try this `console.log(val[0]);` the output is:

[image: here]

Just getting first object in that array.

Now if I try `console.log(val[0].id);` I get:

[image: this error]

Also checked for keys using`console.log(Object.keys(val));` and stringify using `console.log(JSON.stringify(val[0]));`

[image: shown here]

But if I try the exact same processes in chrome console, I get what I need shown

[image: HERE]

This is a React application. I've tried this in VS Code and PyCharm editors as well. I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

### Update

I have added my data and steps taken to arrive a the problem.

```
"variants": [
  {
    "id": 6989569458233,
    "price": "68.00",
    "option1": "color-1",
    "option2": "32",
    "inventory_quantity": 764
  },
  {
    "id": 6989569491001,
    "price": "68.00",
    "option1": "color-1",
    "option2": "32F",
    "inventory_quantity": 158
  },
  {
    "id": 4615727513637,
    "price": "68.00",
    "option1": "color-1",
    "option2": "34D",
    "inventory_quantity": 5
  },
  {
    "id": 4615727906853,
    "price": "68.00",
    "option1": "color-1",
    "option2": "38E",
    "inventory_quantity": 6
  },
  {
    "id": 6989722583097,
    "option1": "color-2",
    "option2": "32E",
    "price": "68.00",
    "inventory_quantity": 1109
  },
  {
    "id": 6989722615865,
    "option1": "color-2",
    "option2": "32F",
    "price": "68.00",
    "inventory_quantity": 1109
  },
  {
    "id": 4615861469221,
    "price": "68.00",
    "option1": "color-2",
    "option2": "34D",
    "inventory_quantity": 1797
  },
  {
    "id": 6989722648633,
    "price": "68.00",
    "option1": "color-2",
    "option2": "34E",
    "inventory_quantity": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 6989722648633,
    "price": "68.00",
    "option1": "color-2",
    "option2": "34F",
    "inventory_quantity": 100
  },
  {
    "id": 6989459193913,
    "price": "68.00",
    "option1": "color-3",
    "option2": "32E",
    "inventory_quantity": 300
  },
  {
    "id": 6989459226681,
    "price": "68.00",
    "option1": "color-3",
    "option2": "32F",
    "inventory_quantity": 320
  },
  {
    "id": 6989459292217,
    "price": "68.00",
    "option1": "color-3",
    "option2": "34F",
    "inventory_quantity": 264
  },
  {
    "id": 4615725842469,
    "price": "68.00",
    "option1": "color-4",
    "option2": "32E",
    "inventory_quantity": 214
  },
  {
    "id": 4615725908005,
    "price": "68.00",
    "option1": "color-4",
    "option2": "34D",
    "inventory_quantity": 133
  },
  {
    "id": 4615725973541,
    "price": "68.00",
    "option1": "color-4",
    "option2": "34F",
    "inventory_quantity": 891
  },
  {
    "id": 6989673398329,
    "price": "68.00",
    "option1": "color-5",
    "option2": "32E(DD)",
    "inventory_quantity": 98
  },
  {
    "id": 6989673431097,
    "price": "68.00",
    "option1": "color-5",
    "option2": "32F",
    "inventory_quantity": 98
  },
  {
    "id": 6989673463865,
    "option1": "color-5",
    "option2": "34D",
    "inventory_quantity": 8
  },
  {
    "id": 6989673496633,
    "price": "68.00",
    "option1": "color-5",
    "option2": "34E",
    "inventory_quantity": 348
  }
]
```

using **lodash** to group in my class component shown below. Here is pass

`input` which is 'color-1', 'color-2',..

**product-detail.js**

```
export default class ProductDetail extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    console.log('props -- ', props);

    this.state = {
        color: 'color-1',
        stock: ''
    }
}


groupBy(input) {
    const groupByColor = _(this.props.variants)
                        .groupBy(x => x.option1)
                        .map((value, key) => ({ color: key, details: value }))
                        .value();
}
```

Using the `groupBy`function I'm using this in my `render()` shown below. Basically trying to extract data using bunch of console outputs shown below just to test. Hope this helps reproduce the issue.

```
render() {
    const val = this.groupBy(this.state.color);
    console.log(val);
    console.log(val[0]);
    console.log(Object.keys(val));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(val[0]));
```

Comment: Please move the errors into the question itself.

Comment: and use text, not images, preferably. images can't be copy-pasted into a text document

Comment: and also please give us sufficient code like the context in which the line occurs otherwise we can't really help you

Comment: Wecome to SO. At the scope you're trying to reference `val[0].id` the reference to `val` is lost thus you get that message. As stated by others before me, we need more context. If you can, provide the simplified version of your code without exposing irrelevant parts. The practice of explaining your actions and intentions in programming is the best practice of them all.

Comment: Do you call console.log(val[0]) and console.log(val[0].id) one after another with no code in-between?

Comment: melpomene, HyperNeutrino - thanks for letting me know. I've included my data and more steps in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cannot read property of undefined` means that the object you were looking for an ID on wasn't there.  Undefined is thrown when the interpreter doesn't understand or can't find the object you were anticipating being there.

In the specific case of your script it means that the object hasn't been fully built and been made available at the moment the script is called, this could be due to the fact that your using an ajax/xhr call and the info doesn't get there at the same time you make the request for the id of the object.

Comment: thanks for helping me understand. This holds true because I tested to get data synchronously using setTimeout() I get the property value. It would be still good to know IF there is a way to do this async and access the property

Comment: I will take a look but I think you can load it with xhr.onload = yourfunc

Comment: Let me know if that helps

Comment: I was looking at the code a little bit closer, and I can't tell where you pull the data from using XHR to make an accurate fix for your application.